# Building a Method In the Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model Quote which persists to a database quotes with columns :quote, :author. My issue is in trying to create a custom display in my Controller.

I have built the follow method and tried many varations. I am trying to get a list of all the authors assigned to various quotes.

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
  acts_as_taggable

  belongs_to :source

  scope :with_source_id, lambda { |id| where("source_id = ?", "#{id}") }

  def quote_authors
    authors = []
    Quote.all.each do |quote|
      authors << quote.author
    end
    authors.uniq!
  end

end
```

Ive tried various versions of self and such, however I can't seem to figure it out. I tried this too

```
def quote_authors(quote_list)
  authors = []
  quote_list.each do |quote|
    authors << quote.author
  end
  authors.uniq!
end
```

Comment: Does the Quote model have a belongs_to :author association?

Comment: so what's wrong with your current method? is it not working or are you looking for something cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method**

I think you'll benefit from looking into [class methods vs instance methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) - one of the main issues I can see is you're calling `quote_authors` as an *instance* method, which, although correct in definition, is not right in application

The problem you have is if you're calling *instance* methods - it has to be on an instance of an object:

```
@user = User.find params[:id] #-> creates instance of object
@user.instance_method #-> calls instance method with data of object
```

If you're using an instance method, it really has to manipulate the instantiated data in your object. Currently, you're not doing this; which would suggest you need to use a *class* method:

```
#app/models/quote.rb
Class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.quote_authors
        Quote.all.each do |quote|
            #...
        end
   end
end
```

--

**System**

As `bratsche` has pointed out - if you are trying to load author names for your `quotes`, you'll be much more suited to using the [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark) system inside Rails:

```
#app/models/quote.rb
Class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    delegate :name, to: :author, prefix: true
end 

#app/models/author.rb
Class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quotes
end
```

This setup will allow you to call:

```
@quote = Quote.find params[:id]
@quote.author_name
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your column `author` is just a string column on your `Quote` model? If that's the case, I'd recommend changing things a little.

Create two models:

```
rails g model author name:string
rails g model quote text:string author:references
```

`app/models/quote.rb`:

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

And `app/models/author.rb`:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotes
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

Now you've got two models. Let's say you're creating a new quote, and you have the text and the name of the author:

```
quote_text = 'Rails is okayish'
author_name = 'bratsche'

author = Author.find_or_create_by_name(author_name)
author.quotes.create(text: quote_text)
```

And to get to your original question, how do you get a list of unique users?

```
Author.all
```

You're (mostly) guaranteed that these will be unique, and you don't need to resort to iterating through a list of all quotes, building a new list with names, and then calling `#uniq!` on them. This way you do it entirely in the database.